# Manipulate two data sets with a sum(if...) or conditional statement that do not have a common identifier with Hive Hadoop Python

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I am trying to run an analysis on the accuracy of geographical ip targeting and have two very large data sets to work with based on conversions of ip addresses to ip integers or `ip_number`(s).

The conversion works as follows

```
ip_number = 16777216*w + 65536*x + 256*y + z   (1)
```

where

```
IP Address = w.x.y.z
```

I've built my two tables in Hadoop with Hive: Table 1 is 2.9MM rows and is organized into geographic locations identified by ranges of `ip_number`(s).  The fields read out:

```
start_ip, end_ip, zipcode, city
```

where the `start_ip` is the minimum `ip_number` and `end_ip` is the max `ip_number` for a given zipcode.

This table is an index of ip_num buckets or ranges and corresponding locations for which I need to analyze usage from another table with unique ip_number(s).

My second table or data set includes interaction and usage data for each individual IP from our server.  So I have 25MM unique `ip_number`(s) with usage data that I need to sum and group by bucket in my first table. The fields read out:

```
ip_number, ip_address, usage
```

There is no common field between the two data sets for a standard join in hive, so I'm stuck.

I've tried using full outer joins, but believe the resulting data set is too large for our Hadoop cluster to handle.  The script times out during map/reduce.

Is there a way with Hive to select the rows from my first table and sum a field from my second table for the activity from ip_numbers that fit within each bucket or range in the first table?  If not, is there a way with Python or R to manipulate the Hadoop tables to accomplish this?

I want the resulting data set to be organized:

```
table_1.ip_start, table_1.ip_end, table_1.zipcode, sum(table_2.usage)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches I can see for this.

1. Create a UDF that will load the geo-ip data using the [Distributed Cache](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) and use that to enrich the usage table
2. Create a UDF that will expand the geo-ip to the full 32-bit ip addresses so you can do a standard join

Neither one of those is all that great.  Option 1 will perform much faster since it will be able to output your results with a single map pass over the usage table.  The downside of this is the memory requirements for loading the 2.9MM rows of geo-ip data.